# How do i make input type from string to date

Tags: jquery, html, razor

I need to set data type from input-field as Time, not as string when field is auto-filled. How can i do that?

Here is the code for input in model.

```
    [Display(Name = "Open time")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter open time!")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string OpenTime { get; set; }
```

Here is Razor code for input

```
<div class="row">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OpenTime)
            <div class="input-field col s12" >
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OpenTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "IDOpenTime"} })

            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OpenTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Code for checkbox.

```
 <div class="container">                               
    <input type="checkbox" name="IsRoundWork" value="true" id="IsRoundWork" />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsRoundWork)                                                            
  </div>
```

And here is JQuery for autofilling the field if checkbox is checked.

```
<script>
$('#IsRoundWork').change(function () {


    if ($('#IsRoundWork').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#IDOpenTime').val('00:00').prop('disabled', true);
        console.log('checked');
    };
    if ($('#IsRoundWork').is(':checked') == false) {
        $('#IDOpenTime').val('').prop('disabled', false);
        console.log('unchecked');
    }

});
```

And when checkbox is checked controller takes "null" value instead of "00:00".
Is there any solution to make data type from input to time type?

Comment: $('.form').find('input:text').each(function() {
       $("<input type='date' />").attr({ name: this.name, value: this.value }).insertBefore(this);
    }).remove();

Comment: i just created codepen url -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzKNOb    it works fine..Please check it once...hopw this is helpful for you

Comment: @NagaSaiA it works, but it still sends datatype text, when i need datatype time. Is that possible to convert text to time with js or jquery?

Comment: Updated codepen - var y= new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + '00:00');
            var x = y.toLocaleTimeString();
            //alert();
            //$('#IDOpenTime').attr("type","date");
            $('#IDOpenTime').val(x);

Comment: Updated codepen with new logic...check it once ,I think it works for you
changed type of input field to time on check
var fieldType = document.getElementById("IDOpenTime");
fieldType ="time"

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/BzKNOb